# Populate Android Table from WS

Tags: java, android, multithreading, web-services

I am trying to make a WS request and populate an Android table with the data that comes back from the WS. 
As I can't make network requests on the main thread I created a thread to handle the request to the WS.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ...

    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
    dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync);
    dialog.setTitle("App");
    dialog.setMessage("Obtaining info");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.show();
   Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try{       
                    ...

                    InputStream message = manager.execWebService(request);

                     ...



                    data = response.toArray(new String[response.size]);

                    numberOfCells = data.length;



                }               
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());

                    this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this.getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });                 
                }                   
                finally{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            }};

thread.start();
```

What I want to do after this is to use the data Array and the numberOfCells int to create the table:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numberOfCells;i++){
        TableLayout table = getTable();
        TableRow row = getRow(data[i]);

        layout.addView(table);
        table.addView(row);
     }
    }
  return view;

 }
```

The problem is I can't access the variables inside the thread (the for cycle is executed at the same time the thread is happening).

If I take this out of the thread I get the "NetworkOnMainThreadException", if I change it to uithread same problem happens.

Help'd be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Huh SO apparently blocks lmgtfy.  But really, there are plenty of examples and tutorials for AsyncTask.

Comment: jajaja sorry @nasch I'll post my attempt to use AsyncTask :/ I just don't understand how to use it

Comment: The good thing about `AsyncTask` is that you do all the "heavy lifting" in a background thread (`doInBackground`) and when you're done, you send the result of the work to the UI thread (`onPostExecute`) where you can add your results to the UI. Look at the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html